Is asking how to use the Japanese mobile phone keyboard on topic?
I recently got the Japanese keyboard on my iPhone, because I’m trying to learn Japanese with Duolingo (though it’s mostly just teaching me romāji, not really the characters or how they go together).
Anyway, is asking how to use it on topic? And how would I phrase it if it is? I don’t know enough about the characters to phrase it myself.

My keyboard looks like this:


The displayed characters are the ones with the vowel /a/, which come at the top of each column in the kana chart. Long-press any of them and the other characters from the same column will appear. ん, which is in its own column, is put in the same group as わ. Swipe your finger to choose a character and release the key. The key at the bottom-left (the one with a smiley face now) can be used to modify the character you have just typed in. Depending on the character, it toggles between up to three types of modification: 1) make it small, 2) add a voiced marker, or 3) add a semi-voiced marker.
